# Wordpress E-commerce

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-ecommerce

I want to add shop to a site. But, before using the tools I need to know if I'm using the right ones

The site is already built in a form of a blog with different articles. In this stage I want to add a shop and I decided to use Woocommerce as a plugin.

The point is that i don't know how to continue. Should i build a child-theme for the shop to take the same style of the website that is already build?

Many of you might suggest shopiffy but at this point I want to have an idea more about the woocommerce.

Comment: great choice, woocommerce is the best choice for eccommerce on wordpress! You do not need a child theme to achieve that, woocommerce is 100 % wordpress friendly and the style of your website will be the style of your theme and any extra css you add yourself, woocommerce won't override anything. You can use woocommerce support if you need any help https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce

Comment: You Always need a child theme ! Even if woocommerce will not erase anything from your theme, any update of theme will delete it's own folder. So to avoid this use child theme, copy woocommerce template file ( if needed)in a new folder woocommerce (follow the wc template structure) and everything will be alright.